# How to represent a non-ideal battery?

Tags: schematics

I'm working on a battery-charging circuit, and I'm investigating how a battery, being charged, is affected over time. I'd like to simulate the circuit in FalStad, so to do that **I need an idea of how to represent a non-ideal battery within a schematic.**

I understand there is an exponential curve in the voltage level of the battery as it charges, which - to me - looks very similar to the charge in a capacitor over time. I also understand that a battery has internal resistance, which is also part of the finished representation. But, that's as far as I've gotten.

I've Googled a lot about "how to represent non-ideal batteries" but I still can't find a detailed answer.

Here is what I *think* a non-ideal battery looks like, but I know it's very easy to overlook things. I use the description "Variable Voltage Source" because the voltage of the battery does change over time.

[image]

Comment: you might consider measuring the resistance, capacitance, and such for an actual battery.  If you measured those at different times in its discharge then you could see if a gain-schedule was viable.

Comment: *I've Googled a lot about "how to represent non-ideal batteries"*... Then it doesn't seem to me that you've spent much time, Tyler. For example, B. Wu, et. al, 2001, used an easy-to-understand RC numerical solver to study the construction of battery models and have shown it provides one powerful approach. Others have investigated the difficulties presented by battery models due to the fact that batteries may operate (or charge) for hours on end, while circuit operations may be on very much shorter time scales, complicating the Spice simulation task. Easy to find this stuff and much more.

Comment: @periblepsis please don't underestimate the effort I've put into this task. What is "easy" to you is not to myself. Or, I should say, "I don't know what I don't know"... I'm not an EE, just a guy with a curiosity, and you're obviously much further into the EE journey than I am. But, as you know, we all learn by doing and by asking - so please take my efforts in the sincerest of ways, as I will take your comment as constructively as it can be taken :)

I'm unfamiliar with the term "Spice simulation task" so I'll use it as a jumping point to research further. Could you link the B. Wu, et. al ?

Comment: @TylerM I'm a hobbyist. No training whatsoever. I just investigate, like you do, when I want to know something. My ability to find papers is just a matter of using the same search tools you likely use. The only possible difference between us might be a few terms that I might recognize that you don't (and visa versa.) So I just don't think you applied yourself, because while I know nothing about this topic (modeling batteries well) I was able to quickly find more than a dozen good papers on the topic in just a few minutes. That's where my judgment comes from. Not because I know more. I don't.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.google.com/search?q=modeling+of+lithium-ion+cell

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Modeling-of-lithium-ion-battery-using-MATLAB-Yao-Aziz/0a44618cd95f5e109b73deef17fc8dcf92f1bdd4

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Different-electrical-equivalent-circuit-models-for-Lithium-Ion-batteries_fig1_322058576

As you can see, it's not easy.

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction. It seems my search terms weren't up to par. I'll have a look at these papers.